# Can't send file as form data using cURL

Tags: php, curl, slim

I am trying to send a cURL request via the command line.  Below is my request

```
curl -i http://localhost/test/index.php 
-X POST 
-F "name=file.png" 
-F "content=@/var/www/html/test/file.png"
```

The problem I'm having is that the file isn't getting sent with the request.  The name is getting sent fine but not the file.  Can anyone see if I am doing anything obviously wrong?

I've check the permission on the file as I thought that might be the problem but they are fine

The backend is written using the PHP Slim framework and I'm doing the following `$app->request->post('content');`

Comment: Try and set the content type `...file.png;type=application/octet-stream` or `image/png`. Maybe it's a backend issue. What makes you say it's not getting sent?

Comment: Your command works just fine. How do you try to read the file in your backend?

Comment: @Phillip I've updated my answer with more details.  So when I try to get the `content` POST variable it is always empty

Comment: @peeskillet When I try to access the `content` POST variable it's always empty

Comment: Why are you talking about POST variable ? When you upload a file you have to deal with the $_FILES var.

Comment: did you try print_r or var_dump($_FILES)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to be able to access the file's contents using `$app->request->post('content');`, your curl request must use a `<` instead of an `@` for the `content` field,

```
curl -i http://localhost/test/index.php -X POST -F "name=file.png" \
  -F "content=</var/www/html/test/file.png"
```

From curl's manpage:

> To  force  the
>                 'content'  part  to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload,
>                 while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.

By using `@`, you marked the field as a file. Technically, this adds a `Content-Disposition` header to the field ([RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt), if you're interested). PHP detects that and automatically stores the field inside `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST`, as  Raphaël Malié remarked in a comment, which is why you can't access the contents using `$app->request->post`.

You should consider to switch to using `$_FILES` in your backend, though, if you want to support uploading using browsers' `<input type=file>` elements and forms. Those always set a `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give this a try.  Which method would you reccomend?  Changing from @ to < and staying with POST or switching to `$_FILES`?

Comment: If you're uncertain, switch to `$_FILES`. ([There's documentation in case you need it](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload).) It's standard to handle uploads that way, and while I can think of situations where you'd want to avoid it, they all are rather esoteric.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46696) in php version 5.2.6 and lower. Verify your php version and test in latest. This might be the problem.

Comment: The question is about using cURL from the command line, not from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

@Bender, use the symbol **@** but make the changes to your PHP Code, such that you make use of **$_FILES** variable. That will help.
Make sure that you provide the Full Absolute path for the cURL. Else you will get the error.

Please refer the same kind of SO Question here: [File Upload to Slim Framework using curl in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183972/file-upload-to-slim-framework-using-curl-in-php)

Hope this helps.